# Current / Context property in class

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I would like to implement an current property in my class which returns the current active context of the class (much like httpcontext.current etc.), like so:

```
using(classA x = new classA(..))
{
    classB.Dosomething();
}
```

where the method dosomething() gets the current context of classA to perform some operation.

How would i go about creating such functionality?

Greetz,
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a `[ThreadStatic] static` Current property, then write `Current = this` in the constructor, and set it to `null` in `Dispose`.  You might want to throw an exception if someone makes a second copy in the same thread.  Alternatively, you could maintain a stack.

Comment: This is the one for me, as i'm not using c# 4.0. Thanx a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it would need some concurrency protection but if you are looking for the singleton way.... (it would also need to implement IDisposable)

```
public class A {
    public static A Current { get { return _instance } }

     private static A _instance {
         get 
         { 
            if(_instance ==null){ 
                 instance = new A();
             } 
             return _instance;
          }
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a "Current" property is a static property kept on a per-thread basis. [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) is ideal for implementing this.

Comment: This would be an option if your are using c# 4.0.